# Org mode customized alphabetic sorting

Tags: org-mode, sorting

The children of a heading at point can be sorted alphabetically
with `C-c ^ a`.  Can this sorting method be customized?
What I want is to sort Greek words according to their Latin
translitteration.  For instance, I want κατά to be sorted as
if it were 'kata'.

Answer (score 1):

According to `org-sort-entries` docstring:

> (org-sort-entries &optional WITH-CASE SORTING-TYPE GETKEY-FUNC
>   COMPARE-FUNC PROPERTY)
>
> ...
>
> The command prompts for the sorting type unless it has been given to the
>   function through the SORTING-TYPE argument, which needs to be a character,
>   (?n ?N ?a ?A ?t ?T ?s ?S ?d ?D ?p ?P ?o ?O ?r ?R ?f ?F ?k ?K).  Here is
>   the precise meaning of each character:
>
> ...
>
> If the SORTING-TYPE is ?f or ?F, then GETKEY-FUNC specifies a function to be
>   called with point at the beginning of the record.  It must return either
>   a string or a number that should serve as the sorting key for that record.

So it seems you could use ?f as SORTING-TYPE and give as GETKEY-FUNC a function returning the latin transliteration of its greek word argument.